# 2+ (multiple) emails in jQuery Validated text input

Tags: jquery, validation, email, multiple-instances

I've been working on this for a few hours now and can't seem to make it work.
I need more than one email in our clients section, in the same input field.

Right now I have (which works great for one email):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#editclient").validate({
            rules: {
            Contact: {
                required: true
            },
            Clientname: {
                required: true
            },
            ClientLogin: {
                required: true
            },
            ClientPassword: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                multiemail: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Contact: {
                required: "Please enter your Contact Nmae."
            },
            Clientname: {
                required: "Please enter your Client Name"
            },
            ClientLogin: {
                required: "Please enter a login."
            },
            ClientPassword: {
                required: "Please enter a password"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter an Email Address",
                multiemail: "You must enter a valid email, or comma separate multiple"
            }
        }
});
});
</script>
    <input type="Text" id="email" name="Email" value="#Trim(Email)#" maxlength="60" class="inputText430 email required">
```

I had found this which is supposed to get the multiple validator working:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
"multiemails",

function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) // return true on optional element
    return true;
    var email = value.split(/[;,]+/); // split element by , and ;
    valid = true;
    for (var i in email) {
        value = email[i];
        valid = valid && jQuery.validator.methods.email.call(this, $.trim(value), element);
    }
    return valid;
},

jQuery.validator.messages.multiemail);
```

But I can't get it to work properly. Can someone please help me get the ability to validate 2 or more emails in one text field?

Thanks in advance.

(edited to add multiemail in rules and messages) 
(edited with solution below)
SOLUTION

```
<form>
    <input id='emailTest' name='emailTest' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "multiemail",
    function (value, element) {
        var email = value.split(/[;,]+/); // split element by , and ;
        valid = true;
        for (var i in email) {
            value = email[i];
            valid = valid && jQuery.validator.methods.email.call(this, $.trim(value), element);
        }
        return valid;
    },
    jQuery.validator.messages.multiemail
);

$("form").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
            emailTest: {
                multiemail: true
            }
        },
    messages: {
            emailTest: {
                multiemail: "You must enter a valid email, or comma separate multiple"
            }
        },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: How does it not work correctly? Do you get an error message, does the function not get called? i suspect an error as you have `jQuery.validator.messages.multiemails` as a paramater in the addMethod function but i do not see a definition for it in your code, so you are probably getting a undefined variable error.

Comment: No errors pop up in console, and the validation of the the email field works like normal, as in will only recognize 1 email as valid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there are some semantic errors in the code which lead to some things happening you aren't expecting.

I have managed to get your custom handler to work by mapping it to a field by name rather than by type - I'm not sure the override works in the plugin.

```
rules: {
    emailTest: {
        multiemail: true
    }
}
```

Also in the handler, you had `multiemails` as the identifier and referred to it as `multiemail` later on, not sure how much of an impact that had.

Here's the full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jbergler/7jXn7/2/

Comment: Thank you very much! Once I had the working example, I could see what was going wrong. Your very direct help is greatly appreciated. Will update above with solution.